# How to install ZendFramework and clt from svn on Mac OS X Lion with the xampp running?

Tags: php, svn, zend-framework

I have a Macbook pro with Lion(10.7.4). I am new in this environment. I was trying to install Zend Framework and zend command line Tool in my mac. I already installed XAMPP  ...
i follow the structure that i read from a book ....

{
     Here are examples of commands you can use to perform these tasks:

```
 shell> cd ZendFramework-XX
   shell> mv library/* /usr/local/lib/php/
   shell> mv bin/* /usr/local/bin/
   shell> chmod +x /usr/local/bin/zf.sh
   shell> ln -s /usr/local/bin/zf.sh /usr/local/bin/zf
```

}

But it does not work for me, I don't know why.

When I run **zf - help** in a terminal I got a error  that tell me the include_path in not define.

How can I fix that or how can I install and run zend framWord correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting a new project, I recommend using Zend Framework 2 not 1.

Here are 2 useful links from the ZF2 quick start guide that will help:

[ZF2 skeleton applicatoin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html)

[ZF2 tool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html)

Try that & let us know how you get on...

Comment: tnx .. i got a this error in terminal when i try to install Composer 
 Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The detect_unicode setting must be disabled.
Add the following to the end of your `php.ini`:
    detect_unicode = Off

A php.ini file does not exist. You will have to create one.
If you can not modify the ini file, you can also run `php -d option=value` to modify ini values on the fly. You can use -d multiple times.
  i try to run that code to change the php.ini but nothing back

Comment: no i try to install it ...  php -d option=value   this command to change the php.ini

Comment: If you are trying to install composer, take a look at http://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: ok .finaly i self-update composer , and install zend FrameWork with useing of composer  that version available in ZF2 skeleton folder ...  . now how can i use CLT tool  to create new project ?! ...  .

Comment: i got a idea .. i decide to install zend form Pear Command and replace the library content with the last release of SVN content .. . is that work you think ?!
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.tool.usage.cli.html